# How to create face out of corner?

Tags: faces, edges

I've frequently found myself in a situation in which I need to create a rectangular face in a corner that only has 2 edges. I created an example:

[image: What I start with]

[image: What I want]

So far I've been doing it by extruding from one edge with Snap to Vertex turned on, then I merge the two vertices and scale the vertex in the open corner by the other vertices. I'm sure there must be an easier way.

Answer (score 2):

- Set snap to 'Vertex' (target) and 'Active' (..,element, source)
- Switch on 'Automatically merge vertices'
- In vertex mode, select the two vertices at the ends of one of the inner edges, corner last.
- <kbd>E</kbd> extrude the edge implied by the two vertices, snapping the corner vertex to the one at the other end of its edge.

It depends, really, this way isn't necessarily faster than yours, but I nearly always have my snap set this way anyway.. and if fiddling, often use the auto-weld. Perhaps the only point is, you don't need to be in Edge mode to extrude the edge.

Comment: Actually, it does seem to be faster. I forgot the Automatically Merge Vertices option. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I recently learned about the F2 addon, which seems to be able to do this exact thing with only a couple clicks

Edit: It looks like, with the F2 add-on, you simply enter Vertex mode, click the vertex in the corner, then just press F.